# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager no more synchronous calls?

Tags: asp.net-identity

It seems that all UserManager calls are now asynchronous (based on the nightly builds, e.g.: UserManager.IsInRole has been removed). This not only creates a ton of work (I subclass Controller and override OnActionExecuting which then uses UserManager), but is also aborts with "Invalid column name 'IsConfirmed'.\r\nInvalid column name 'IsConfirmed'.\r\nInvalid column name 'IsConfirmed'." -- Yes, three times.

The line of code which performs the abortion:

```
bool inRole = await um.IsInRoleAsync(userId, role.Name).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

regardless of the boolean value passed to ConfigureAwait. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you're getting an unusual error *from a nightly build*, the best option is to contact the ASP.NET team.

Comment: I worked around it by adding the IsConfirmed column to my extension of dbo.AspNetUsers table. All is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
private UserManager<TenantUser> usermanager= new UserManager<TenantUser>(new UserStore<TenantUser>(_dbContext));

bool isUserInRole = usermanager.IsInRole(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId(), "Admin");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Nilesh. Ignore the async stuff, the sync methods have been restored. Still aborts. I don't want the CurrentPrincipal.Identity, this code lists all the registered users on the system by role. My um is the same as your usermanager.

Comment: i'm confused little bit..Actually above code determines whether the current loggedin user has `Admin` role or not

Comment: In the original code, role.Name is a variable which is inside a loop going through all the roles.